# My socket io is working but when I add new data, it's not real time, ReactJS, Express, Mongoose

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose, socket.io

I really can't find an answer in the internet so I want to ask here. My socket io works, cause I can display data from the backend on the first load of my page, but when I add new data, I still have to refresh my page so that my frontend would be updated, it's not yet real time. I use express router/rest api to add new data to the database. And I also want to ask, why I have to add { transports: ['websocket', 'polling', 'flashsocket'] } on my frontend? I see others do it without the transports thing, but when I do CORS error occurs. Thank you!

This is my React JS code on file App.js. (I didn't include the const App = () => {....}, but the state and useEffect is inside of the const App)

```
import io from "socket.io-client";
const socket = io("http://localhost:3001", { transports: ['websocket', 'polling', 'flashsocket'] });

const [rooms,setRooms] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    socket.emit("rooms");

    socket.on("rooms", rooms=> {
        setRooms(rooms);
    })
},[])
```

This is my app.js (node/express)

```
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(http);

const viewRooms = require("./events/rooms");

const onConnection = (socket) => {
     viewRooms(io,socket);
}

io.on("connection",onConnection);
```

This is rooms.js file on my events folder

```
const Rooms= require("./../models/Rooms");

module.exports = (io,socket) => {
    const view = () => {
        Rooms.find()
        .then(rooms=> {
            io.emit("rooms",rooms);
        })

    }
    socket.on("rooms",view);
 }
```

The submit function I use to add data to the database

```
const submitHandle = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('name',addForm.name);
    addForm.description.forEach((val,key) => {
        formData.append("article[" + key + "]" + "[" + Object.keys(val) + "]",val.paragraph);
    })
    addForm.images.forEach(val => {
        formData.append("image",val);
    })
    formData.append('date',addForm.date);

    let token = "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjYwNDU2ZmNhNTI3ZTdhMGEwODY0NjVjNSIsImlhdCI6MTYxODI3NzIyNX0.w6eBHJC72xo-NRPtzJ3gKu_hIY70eCk_-K3-pkO4bAc";        

    fetch("http://localhost:3001/rooms/upload",{
        method : "POST",
        body : formData,
        headers : {
            "Authorization" : token
        }
    })
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(rooms=> {
        console.log(rooms);
        alert(rooms.message);
    })
}
```

And this is my code on my express route (post)

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const Rooms = require("./../models/Rooms ");
const auth = require("./../authorization");
const passport = require("passport");
const multer = require("multer");
require("./../passport-setup");

// IMAGE DESTINATION AND FILENAME
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination : (req,file,cb) => {
        cb(null,"public/images")
    },
    filename : (req,file,cb) => {
        cb(null, Date.now() + "-" + file.originalname)
    }
})

// upload
const upload = multer({ storage : storage});

// upload rooms
router.post("/upload",upload.array("image",10),passport.authenticate("jwt",{session : false}),auth,(req,res,next) => {

let allDescription = req.body.description;

req.body.images = req.files.map(file => {
    return(
        {
            roomName : req.body.name,
            image : "/public/" + file.filename
        }
    )
})
Rooms .create(req.body)
.then(rooms=> {
    res.send({
        message : "Rooms uploaded!",
        success : true,
        rooms
    })
})
.catch(next);
```

})

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your question, we'd have to see a lot more logging info to now exactly what is going on.  It seems possible that your client-side `socket.emit("news");` is perhaps happening too early before your socket.io connection is fully established and perhaps before the server is ready for the incoming request.  You can fully log every single socket.io event and probably determine what's going on.

> And I also want to ask, why I have to add { transports: ['websocket', 'polling', 'flashsocket'] } on my frontend?

If you don't list `websocket` as the first transport, then socket.io starts with a few http polling requests and those http requests are subject to CORS.  The webSocket transport is not subject to CORs, so if you force it to use that first, then no CORs.  FYI, the http polling that socket.io uses is only really there to detect situations where the webSocket transport is not supported or is blocked.  If you aren't concerned about that, then you can really just do this in the front-end:

```
{ transports: ['websocket'] }
```

Or, you could remove the transports option completely from the client and then implement support for CORs on your server so that the CORs polling request will be allowed.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your answer on the first part of my question. I only have 1 socket.io event since I'm currently learning how to use it. How to know if my client-side: socket.emit("news",news) is happening too early? On the first load of page my socket io works, it can fetch data from the database and my state is updated, but when I add new data using express router/api, my socket.io doesn't work real time, so I have to refresh my page again. Now, I just added socket.emit("news",news) on the function that adds data using the express api (on the frontend ofcourse), and it works.

Comment: So do I have to add socket.emit("news",news) on every functions that connects to my express api? Or what I did was wrong ?

Comment: @benjamin_nmn - When you do `const socket = io("http://localhost:3001", { transports: ['websocket', 'polling', 'flashsocket'] });`, it does not instantly connect - it takes some time.  In fact, there's a `connect` event that occurs on the socket when the client connection is ready.  I'm guessing that maybe you're trying to send on the socket before it is ready.

Comment: How can I make sure that before I send on the socket, the server is ready? And why it works on the first load, but not when I add new data to the database using rest api?

Comment: @benjamin_nmn - Are you showing your rest api code?  I don't see it.  Can't answer questions about code we can't see.

Comment: sorry about that, I just edited my post, and added my function that adds new data. Please see it, thank you! Ps: the token is just temporary, cause I'm not fixing my login form yet.

Comment: @benjamin_nmn - That shows the client-side API code, but still no server side code for the matching route which is where info would have to be sent to each connected client.

Comment: I just edited my post, please check if the codes I provided is already enough, thank you so much. Ps: I changed news to rooms, cause I only used news for trial.

Comment: @benjamin_nmn - I'm confused.  You show a route for `router.post("/upload", ...)`, but I don't see how that route is connected at all to socket.io?

Comment: Actually it's not, what I did is separate my routes and socket.io, I thought that I could create a socket.io event that takes data from the database using mongoose and send it to the client, and use routes to add data to the database. So what I did was wrong?

Comment: @benjamin_nmn - So, the API call adds some data to the database.  Exactly how you do you expect a socket.io message gets sent to the client to tell them about the new data?  I don't see any code that does that.  I'm sorry, but it is your responsibility to write a question that contains all the information we might need to help you.  This is a lot of work for me to try to keep unconvering what else you need to add to the question.

Comment: Okay, I really thought what I did would work. Sorry for the trouble, and thank you for your time.